# The meaning of "capture of ? e" in Java

Tags: java, generics, invariance

In IntelliJ IDEA, especially when I create the instance of `Collection` class like:

```
Collection<?> collection = ...;
collection.
```

And try typing the method `add`, IntelliJ helps me telling that `add`'s first argument is `capture of ? e`.

Anyway, I can't use any value as the argument like:

```
collection.add(new Integer(5));
```

and the message is

> add(`capture<?>`) in `Collection` cannot be applied to (`java.lang.Integer`)

What does it mean?

Comment: It means that your collection is _declared_ to contain elements of _some_ type and _not_ `java.lang.Object`, so the compiler cannot an integer.

Comment: Another one worth reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv thank you, helping me a great deal!

Comment: To understand the concept of wildcard capture: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html

Comment: @AndyTurner thank you as well, nice answer from `@anoopelias`